# Flattening an array only one layer?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there any built-in numpy function that would get:

```
a=np.asarray([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]]])
```

And would return:

```
b=[[1,2],[3,4],[1,2],[3,4]]
```

? Something like like one layer flattening.

P.S. I am looking for a vectorized option otherwise this dumb code is available:

```
flat1D(a):
   b=np.array([])
   for item in a:
      b=np.append(b,item)
   return b
```

Comment: my dumb code is not working! :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply reshape the array.

```
>>> a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1])
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

The shown code returns a 1D array, to do this:

```
>>> a.ravel()
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Or, if you are sure you want to copy the array:

```
>>> a.flatten()
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

The difference between ravel and flatten primarily comes from the fact that flatten will always return a copy and ravel will return a view if possible and a copy if not.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the dimensions of the new array you can specify these as a tuple `(4,2)` and use `.reshape()`

```
a.reshape((4,2))
```

Comment: This answer is far too lacklustre and does not contain any particularly useful information. It's best to actually include an explanation of the techniques and concepts you have used in your answer so that newcomers can understand them too.